# STM32f10x -- ADS1115 -- I2C -- AF flag is always set

Tags: c, stm32, i2c

I have a problem to get an ACK from the ADS1115 when I send it address.
I use Embitz IDE and STM32 Standard Peripheral Libraries.

I always get the AF = 1.

This is the code:

```c
#include "stm32f10x_conf.h"

#define ADS1115_Address  0x90

int main(void) {
    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStructure;
    I2C_InitTypeDef I2C_InitStructure;
    RCC_APB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB1Periph_I2C1, ENABLE);
    RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_GPIOB, ENABLE);

    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_6 | GPIO_Pin_7;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AF_OD;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz;
    GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStructure);
    GPIO_PinRemapConfig(GPIO_Remap_I2C1, ENABLE);

    I2C_DeInit(I2C1);

    I2C_InitStructure.I2C_Ack = I2C_Ack_Enable;
    I2C_InitStructure.I2C_AcknowledgedAddress = I2C_AcknowledgedAddress_7bit;
    I2C_InitStructure.I2C_ClockSpeed = 100000;
    I2C_InitStructure.I2C_DutyCycle = I2C_DutyCycle_2;
    I2C_InitStructure.I2C_Mode = I2C_Mode_I2C;
    I2C_InitStructure.I2C_OwnAddress1 = 0;
    I2C_Init(I2C1, &I2C_InitStructure);
    I2C_Cmd(I2C1, ENABLE);

    while(1) {
        I2C_GenerateSTART(I2C1, ENABLE);
        I2C_Send7bitAddress(I2C1, ADS1115_Address, I2C_Direction_Transmitter);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that all your code? You're falling out of your `main` function if so.

Comment: sorry but when i wrote the question something wrong happend but now this is the code ..

Comment: What he's saying is that `int main (void)` makes no sense in bare metal microcontroller applications.

Comment: i have read many example codes and  int main(void) is always used i didnt get the point can you explain more plz??

Comment: im kind of beginner guys so any tip would be appreciated ...

Comment: It makes sence of the exit routine makes any use of the returned value. @Ludlin not every startup/exit code in the bare metal programming is as simple as the standard cube .ones

Comment: What is your microcontroller doing when you return from `main`?

Comment: STM32 Standard Peripheral Libraries are not supported any more. Better use HAL Libs. And how do you chek ACK status?

Comment: the AF flag is "1" and that means no ack from the slave is it right ??

Comment: i have noticed that when i run the program in debug mode i have this problem (AF=1) ,but when i run it  continually i get results from the ads1115 but the result is always 0xffff ...

Comment: This code is too ugly. Show the rest. How do you get the data? You can do this much more easier with HAL lib.

Comment: ok .. can anyone pls give a link to the HAL library files and where can i find a description to it ???

Comment: @MohammadAffash Start from [here](http://www.st.com/en/development-tools/stm32cubemx.html)

Comment: Thanx alot @Bulkin

Answer (score -1):

ads1115 just have 4 adress
0x48 0x49 0x4A 0x4B

You can find addressing on datasheet

you can not use 0x90 adress for ads1115